# D3 Matrix of Objects

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, matrix

I'm trying to display a matrix of objects in simple html using D3.

```
let matrix = [
  [{firstName:'John', lastName:'Doe'},{firstName:'Jane',lastName:'Doe'}],
  [{firstname:'Henry',lastname:'Smith'},{firstName:'Jane',lastName:'Smith'}],
  [{firstname:'Fred',lastname:'Fox'}]
]
```

Notice, the matrix may not be have the same number of columns.  Is that a problem for D3?

I am trying to render them as a list in a set if `div` elements. Following  [this](http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6734025) pattern.  So far I have

```
let container = d3.select('#myContainerDiv');

let rows = container.selectAll('div');
rows.data(matrix);
rows.enter().append('div');

let cols = rows.selectAll('span');
cols.data(function(row){
  return row;}, function(row,i){
  return row[i].lastName+row[i].firstName;});

cols.enter().append('span')
  .classed('myClass',true)
  .html(function(cell){
  return cell.lastName+', '+cell.firstName;
});
```

It creates the 'row' div elements but does not populate them with 'span' data elements.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue with a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/2g5xumdh/

```
var my = d3.select('#my');

var dataSet = [
  [{firstName:'John', lastName:'Doe'},{firstName:'Jane',lastName:'Doe'}],
  [{firstName:'Henry',lastName:'Smith'},{firstName:'Jane',lastName:'Smith'}],
  [{firstName:'Fred',lastName:'Fox'}]
];

var rows = my.selectAll('div')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('div');

var col = rows.selectAll('span').data(function(d,i){
  return d;
},function(d,i){
 return d.lastName+d.firstName;
});

col.enter().append('span').html(
function(d,i){return '&bull; '+ d.firstName + ' '+ d.lastName+' ';}
);
```